# How Much Bitcoin Does Satoshi Have?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

How can we calculate all Satoshi Bitcoin holdings?

I know about the genesis address `1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa` and then there are lots of mining addreses

When did he stopped mining, sending and receiving money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **How Much Bitcoin Does Satoshi Have?**

From [CoinCodex](https://coincodex.com/article/22945/satoshi-nakamoto-net-worth/)

> Although we can’t know exactly how much BTC Satoshi was able to mine, the commonly accepted estimate is that he mined approximately 1.1 million BTC.

That is over $51 billion at today's exchange rate.

---

> **How can we calculate all Satoshi Bitcoin holdings?**

You have to guess which addresses Satoshi Nakamoto created. This is difficult. Some estmate 20000 addresses.

According to [BitKan](https://bitkan.com/learn/what-is-satoshi-wallet-address-how-many-bitcoins-does-satoshi-nakamoto-have-11741)

> Satoshi Nakamoto is believed to hold almost 1.1 million Bitcoins. It's important to keep in mind that this number is just an estimate. Due to the incomplete identity of the public wallet addresses used by the entity, it is challenging to trace the Bitcoin that Satoshi owns .
>
> The Satoshi Nakamoto Bitcoin wallet value of 1.1 million is based on a trend that was discovered in the first two years of the Bitcoin mining trend. The **Patoshi pattern**, which was discovered by **Sergio Demian Lerner**, a chain analyst at RSK Labs, is the most Well-known example of this pattern.
>
> A research published in 2013 shows that a single person mined the great bulk of the first batch of Bitcoins. According to ***'s estimates, a single miner may have processed around 22,000 blocks in the first year of Bitcoin, and may have gathered 1.8 million Bitcoin in total, 1.1 million of which has not been spent.

---

- [The Patoshi Pattern](https://www.elementus.io/blog-post/an-inside-look-at-clustering-methods-the-patoshi-pattern)